# Consume crossdomain WebAPI with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to consume Mongolab WebAPI with jQuery v1.9 `$.ajax` like this

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/my-db/collections/my-coll?apiKey=myAPIKey",
  type: "GET",
  contentType: "application/json"
});
```

and I thought it is a crossdomain request, and the contentType should be `application/javascript` and dataType should be `JSONP`, but surprisingly, it successfully return the json result with `ContentType 'application/json'`. I'm quite confuse that if jquery encapsulate the ajax call and automatically call the server with `application/javascript`.

Could someone give me an explanation although this may looks a rookie question?

Comment: What browsers did you test in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I try to run that code in safari with jsfiddle.net, I get:

`Failed to load resource: Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

This means that safari asked `api.mongolab.com` if `fiddle.jshell.net` is allowed to access it via an ajax call, and mongolab.com either did not respond or it responded with "no, don't allow it". Perhaps if your domain name is localhost or if it is registered with mongolab, then it will be allowed to execute.

However it will only work in modern browsers. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: Hi Abhi, thanks for your help, like you said, it's only work in modern browser, I was test under chrome and firefox, and the I check the response header the Access-Control-Allow-Origin is set to ture, I think this is because mongolab wildcardly allows request from other domain, your answer is helpful, thanks

Answer (score -1):

try setting crossDomain as true

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/my-db/collections/my-coll?apiKey=myAPIKey",
  type: "GET",
  contentType: "application/json",
  crossDomain : true
});
```

Comment: Hi Bharath, thanks for your suggestion, I don't think this is my problem. and the crossDomain will be automaticlly set to true if the url you request is not same as your application domain if you look into jquery source code. still thanks for your help